# Connected EV3 bricks don't react (EV3 Classroom)

Tags: ev3, bluetooth, connections

I have a big robot that needs four big motors to drive it and two small motors for other functions -> I need two bricks to communicate with each other because they need to use the same sensors.

I get the bricks connected via Bluethooth, but when I send messages with the "send message" and "when I receive message" block, the other brick does not respond.
What could be the reason for this?

I use:

- Both bricks with 1.09H
- EV3 Classroom (1.5.3)
- The bricks have different names

Answer (score 2):

Brick-to-brick communication is not possible using the EV3 Classroom software. You will need to use a different programming environment.

The broadcast blocks in EV3 Classroom (and other Scratch-based programming languages) only send messages between stacks of blocks within the Scratch program. They do not send messages to other connected EV3s.

[image: screenshot of scratch broadcast blocks]